# Android JNI Error : warning: initialization makes integer from pointer without a cast

Tags: android, java-native-interface

I'm new in Android JNI. I'm sending JAVA object from my java file to C code given below. My jObject info contains char[] values in java.Actually i think I'm unable to convert jObject to char and therefore when i compile this code i get the error:

warning: initialization makes integer from pointer without a cast

My C File :

```
typedef struct {
    unsigned char reg_chal[32];
    unsigned char aid[32];
} reg_info_t;

JNIEXPORT jint JNICALL Java_com_marakana_NativeLib_reg(JNIEnv *env,jclass obj,jobject info ,jchar details,jchar reg_code)
{
    reg_info_t regInfo;
    jclass clazz;
    jfieldID fid;
    jmethodID mid;

    jint status =0; 

    LOGD("NDK:LC: [%s]", "JNI Function call started");
    LOGD("NDK:LC: [%s]", details);
    LOGD("NDK:LC: [%c]", reg_code);

    //GetInfo(entryInfo);   // fills in the entryInfo

    clazz = (*env)->GetObjectClass(env, info);
    if (0 == clazz)
    {
        printf("GetObjectClass returned 0\n");
        return(-1);
    }

    jchar reg_chal = (*env)->NewStringUTF(env,regInfo.reg_chal);
    fid = (*env)->GetFieldID(env,clazz,"reg_chal","Ljava/lang/String;");
    (*env)->SetObjectField(env,info,fid,reg_chal);
    LOGD("NDK:LC: [%c]", reg_chal);

    jchar aid = (*env)->NewStringUTF(env,regInfo.aid );
    fid = (*env)->GetFieldID(env,clazz,"aid ","Ljava/lang/String;");
    (*env)->SetCharField(env,info,fid,aid );
    LOGD("NDK:LC: [%c]", aid);


    //reg_step_1(info ,  details, reg_code);
    //status = reg_step_1(info ,  details, reg_code);
    return status; 

}
```

Please help me how to fix this error of conversion?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`NewStringUTF` doesn't return a `jchar`; it returns a `jstring`, which is really just a synonym for `jobject`.

You should change `jchar reg_chal` to `jstring reg_chal`, and change `jchar aid` to `jstring aid`.

Comment: @ Struart Cook : Thanks for teh help dude . It's building the lib well now . But I'm getting a new type of  error  now        : I/DEBUG   (   31): *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** ***

I/DEBUG   (   31): Build fingerprint: 'generic/sdk/generic/:2.2/FRF91/43546:eng/test-keys'

I/DEBUG   (   31): pid: 692, tid: 692  >>> com.marakana <<<

I/DEBUG   (   31): signal 11 (SIGSEGV), fault addr 00000064                                                                         Any idea how to fix Signal 11 error in ndk ? Thanks for teh help